# Button event is not invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've problem that my button click is not working ,currently I use the following code ,this is the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
     <input  id="button2" value="Click Me 2"  />

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is file JS**

```
$('#button').click(onClick);

var onClick = function() {
    debugger;
    alert('Hi');
};
```

in addition I want that when I click I will get **the context** (maybe this or event of the selected button in the onClick event ,what IM doing wrong here?

Comment: `$(#button).on('click', function(){...})`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar-Thanks but I dont want to use it internal...

Comment: put your buttons inside body and bind the click event on doc ready block.

Comment: @Jai-Try it witout sucess,any other idea?

Comment: @JhonDree bind your events in doc ready block.

Comment: little bit confusing can you please tell us what is your ultimate aim ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
     <input type="button" id="button2" value="Click Me 2"  />

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var onClick = function() {

    alert('Hi');
};
                  $('#button').click(onClick);

});
```

Comment: Thanks voted up! btw if I want that every button will invoke diffrent event how should I do that ?

Comment: @JhonDree what do you mean by each button has different event ? can you more specific ?

Comment: Currenlty the events are on button $('#button') but I need that every button will open different event,how should I do that ? for example button 2 should open event onClick2....

Comment: @JhonDree Event is not like functions ,button  Click is an event .so there is nothing like onclcik2 event onclick3 event . Are you trying to open different function in each button click event ??

Comment: @JhonDree or something like each button click event will alert different things ?? did you mean something like that ??

Comment: @JhonDree just go through this it will help you http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: @JhonDree sorry, did not get you. explain more so i can help you .

Answer (score 0):

Your html Dom isn't there when you are trying to initiate the event handler. Try to wrap yor function in document ready or include the javascript after the html part, directly in front of the closing body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
     <input  id="button2" value="Click Me 2"  />
<script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please provide example ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function like this :

```
function onClick() {
    alert('Hi');
};
```

Or link the button to the function AFTER var declaration :

```
var onClick = function() {
    debugger;
    alert('Hi');
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

Comment: No. that is not the issue.